# The Guardian : "The real rivalry between Oxford and Cambridge is how low they can go for money", what is the exact meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning

This sentence looks vague to me :

> The real rivalry between Oxford and Cambridge is how low they can go for money

Does *can go for money* has the meaning of "*obtain funds*" ? Is it less precise: any money wherever it comes, or more precise: deserve funds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the definitions of “low” is unethical or undignified. Going low in this case means resorting to distasteful methods of obtaining money.

The writer is criticizing both Oxford and Cambridge by saying they are both resorting to shameful methods of obtaining money. They are suggesting (somewhat facetiously) that it is almost as if they are competing with each other to see which one can go lowest (in terms of ethics).

Comment: I was completely misled.